# Why "Page not found" when I click on login button in bms_homepage.html?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

URLS.PY

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
    path('login', views.login, name='login'),
]
```

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def homepage(request):
    return render(request, 'bms_homepage_template/bms_homepage.html')

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'bms_homepage_template/login_page.html')
```

login_page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>LOGIN INTO YOUR ACCOUNT</h1>

    <form action="">
        Account Number:
        <input type="text"> <br>
        Password:
        <input type="text"> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

bms_homepage.html

```
<a href="login_page.html"><button id="login">LOGIN</button></a>
```

What i want to do is from homepage.html, when i click on login button it should open login_page.html
but it is showing me this error.

> Page not found

Please explain in simple words.

Comment: Please don’t use all caps in your title. It’s considered as yelling.

Comment: Because you have no `login_page.html`. The page is named `login` in your `urls.py`.

Answer (score 1):

You should refer url pattern name rather then template name.

In your case url pattern name is `login`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ..
    path('login', views.login, name='login'), <<<--- "name" argument value
]
```

To refer to this pattern you should use url-reversion template tag like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">...</a>
```